# Trouble with pointers and reading information into an array

Tags: c++

I'm having some issues when trying to read in some values to a dynamically allocated array. Everything looks okay to me, but when the code is run, only the last entry into the array is shown. The code is below. If you could give me some recommendations I would appreciate it.

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("MovieStatistics.txt");

int numOfStudents = 0;
string first, last, line;
int movies;

int *numMovies = nullptr;
string *names = nullptr;

if (!infile) {
    cout << "Error opening file";
} else {
    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        numOfStudents++;
        stringstream ss(line);
        ss >> first >> last >> movies;
    }

    numMovies = new int[numOfStudents];
    names = new string[numOfStudents];
}

for (int i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++) {
    names[i] = first + " " + last;
    numMovies[i] = movies;
}
```

Comment: After you count the lines, you need to rewind the file and read the data into the arrays. (Or just use `std::vector`).

Comment: This code doesn't have anything that would print contents of the arrays. Also your `while (getline(infile, line))` loop constantly overwrites the contents of your 3 strings, never storing them in the arrays

Comment: assuming this is in a `main()` you should have a `return` after you print your error message in your `if`, otherwise it will continue to the for loop

Comment: Do not use `new` and `delete`.  In modern C++, those are only for doing somewhat advanced things. For now, pretend you never heard of them.  For the case at hand, use `std::vector`. When presenting questions on SO, post a complete program that can be cut and pasted in one piece into a file and then compiled with no editing. Read this: [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you assign `first` and `last` inside the read loop but you don't store the values in an array or vector so they contain the last values.

To get it to work you could edit the code to:

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("data.txt");

int numOfStudents = 0;
string first, last, line;
int movies;

int *numMovies = nullptr;
string *names = nullptr;

// get the number of students
while (getline(infile, line))
    numOfStudents++;

numMovies = new int[numOfStudents];
names = new string[numOfStudents];

// clear the buffer
infile.clear();
infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

int i = 0;
while(getline(infile, line)){
    stringstream ss(line);
    ss >> first >> last >> movies;
    names[i] = first + " " + last;
    numMovies[i] = movies;
    ++i;
}

for(int i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++)
    cout << names[i] << endl;

// don't forget to free memory:
delete[] movies;
delete[] names;
infile.close();
```

What I recommend is to use class `vector`:

```
std::ifstream infile("data.txt");
std::string sLine;
std::vector<std::string> vecNames;

while(getline(infile, sLine))
    vecNames.push_back(sLine);

auto size = vecNames.size();
//for(auto x : vecNames)
//      std::cout << x << std::endl;

for(int i(0); i != size; ++i)
    std::cout << vecNames[i] << std::endl;

infile.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This solution worked perfectly!

Comment: @CoreyShouse: I edited: Always close the stream objects when you're done with them; calling `out/in_sream.close()`.

Comment: Recommend marking where you made changes. I don't think you need to explain them in this case, but dropping in a highly visible comment will hep future readers.

Answer (score 0):

So you loop over the file, repeatedly reading data into `first`, `last` and `movies` — overwriting the previous values each time.

Much later, you take the *current* value of those variables, and write it to your dynamic arrays `numOfStudents` times.

You probably want to rewind the stream and loop over the file again so that you can pull out all the data; you never actually stored each sample the first time around.